# Multiple lines output write to txt file with echo

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline, sh, echo

I want to write my last commit to txt file with echo.When I check my last commit with echo, system shows the commit information with 3 lines.But when I try to write those output in txt file, after first lines getting error.

I wrote those script on jenkinsfile. Thats why I try to add #/bin/bash and -e in sh part but still getting error with same error.

Script in jenkinsfile:

> ```
> last_commit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log -1").trim()
> echo "${last_commit}"
>
> log = log.plus("Last Commit: ${last_commit}\n\r") 
> sh 'echo Last Commit: ${last_commit} >> log.txt'
> ```

Output Results:

```
2019-08-01 11:07:32.261  + git log -1
[Pipeline] echo
2019-08-01 11:07:32.306  commit 546548643naseqw1a77325a0345251465519d6
2019-08-01 11:07:32.307  Author: Jack <jack@sample.com>
2019-08-01 11:07:32.307  Date:   Thu Aug 1 11:07:18 2019 
2019-08-01 11:07:32.307  
[Pipeline] sh
2019-08-01 11:07:32.678  + echo -e Last Commit: commit 546548643naseqw1a77325a0345251465519d6
2019-08-01 11:07:32.678  -e Last Commit: commit 546548643naseqw1a77325a0345251465519d6
2019-08-01 11:07:32.678  /jenkins/workspace/sample_job@tmp/durable-013cf5ad/script.sh: 10: /jenkins/workspace/sample_job@tmp/durable-05235d/script.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
```

Comment: seems double quote missing around `Last Commit: ${last_commit}` in sh command

Comment: I tried it not worked

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
 sh """ 
  #!/bin/bash
  set -ex
  echo "Last Commit: ${last_commit}" >> changelog.txt 
  """
```